# Why is my themes.xml file not displaying any items?

Tags: android, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxaDK.png)

I'm relatively new to app development and currently following a tutorial on creating a calculator app. I've successfully created the user interface (UI) for my app. In the tutorial, the instructor modifies the button colors by defining color items in the `themes.xml` file. However, when I opened my `themes.xml` file, I couldn't find the expected `<item>` elements to define these colors. Instead, I found something different, which is shown in the screenshot.

I tried creating an item with the same color but obviously it didn't work.

Comment: Please don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Google is constantly changing the default projects setup from version to version of Android Studio. You may have to manually add color items to your file, or they might be defined inside a different xml file in the `res/values` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can add colors like this to your colors.xml file.

```
<color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
<color name="purple_1">#8800D1</color>
<color name="purple_2">#9C27B0</color>
<color name="blue_1">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="blue_2">#03A9F4</color>
```

And then you can use them in the themes.xml file

```
<item name="colorText" type="color">@color/blue_1</item>
<item name="colorButton" type="color">@color/purple_1</item>
```

Or you can change your primary color as suggested in the comment in the themes.xml file

```
 <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_2</item>
```

You can use the colors you added in your xml design files such as

```
android:textColor="@color/colorText"
```